# opera and firefox syntax for radial gradients

Tags: firefox, css, webkit, opera, radial-gradients

Making a vignette of sorts using webkit/moz radial gradients. I have the correct syntax and effect for webkit.. but can't get moz or opera dialed in right. Moz is kind of oblongish.. Opera is nonexistent.

Advice?

CSS

```
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(center, 50% 10px, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(29,29,29,1));
background:-moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(29,29,29,1));
background:-o-radial-gradient(center, 50% 10px, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(29,29,29,1));
```

---

```
background:-webkit-gradient( radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 960, from(rgba(255,255,255,0)), to(rgba(29,29,29,.4)));
background:-moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0px, rgba(29,29,29,.4) 960px);
```

Answer (score 2):

Radial gradients for FF and webkit: http://www.westciv.com/tools/radialgradients/index-moz.html

Radial gradients are not yet supported by Opera :( try canvas:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/#gradients

Comment: @technopeasant final answer, changed it again :)

Comment: way cool, thanks for the tool. ended up tooling through it and figured it out